# Installing docker-compose on Amazon EC2 Linux 2. 9kb docker-compose file

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

First of all, let me state I'm not the most virtuous of Linux users, so bear with me...
Below is a brief run-down of all the steps I took. Ultimately the question/issue is is that it seems impossible for me to get a proper docker-compose installation downloaded.

1. Followed instructions to install docker https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html
2. sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.26.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

Tried 4 variations of the above command to try to install docker-compose. As shown in the URLs below.

1. https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/php/how+to+install+docker+compose+in+ec2
2. https://portal.cloud303.io/forum/aws-1/question/i-want-to-install-docker-compose-on-an-amazon-linux-2-ec2-instance-9
3. https://acloudxpert.com/how-to-install-docker-compose-on-amazon
4. https://gist.github.com/npearce/6f3c7826c7499587f00957fee62f8ee9
   When typing "docker-compose", "sudo docker-compose" etc. All it will say is

"Line 1: Not: command not found".

It seems to be the issue that the docker-compose file is only 9kb in size. Because this is what I get back every time I use the above mentioned docker-compose install sequences.

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100     9  100     9    0     0     58      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    58
```

This issue is sort of addressed here:
https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6268

Where it is said that the OS is not supported or that we're running a 32bit instance, but of which seem to be strange because all the above tutorials are specifically for AWS EC2 Linux 2.

fwiw 'uname -m' returns aarch64.

So, does anyone have an idea of how to get a full-sized version of docker-compose instead of the 9kb file?

Thanks!

Comment: The Docker documentation includes instructions to [Install Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/).  In addition to downloading the binary, you need to make it executable, and you may need additional shared-library dependencies.

Answer (score 105):

followed the link to install the docker-compose [link](https://gist.github.com/npearce/6f3c7826c7499587f00957fee62f8ee9)

Basically, thee are only two steps as below:

```
sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/latest/download/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

docker-compose version
```

Comment: This works if `https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/latest/download/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)` resolves to an existing URL, but as the OP is running on aarch64 architecture (the result of `uname -m`), the downloaded docker-compose "binary" will only consist of a "Not Found" message. I posted an alternative approach as a separate answer. And maybe some day docker-compose will also provide an arm64 binary.

Comment: @TillKuhn is correct. I am using `EC2 t4g` family with aach64` which is based on AMD architecture and I face the same issue as OP. I resolved this with a different approach which I will post as answer.

Comment: FWIW as of 18th October 2021 it seems like `aarch64` is now a supported binary as the https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/latest/download/docker-compose-Linux-aarch64 link now resolves to a build of `docker-compose@v2.0.1`

Comment: Does this install compose v2? After doing this, `docker compose` says "compose is not a docker command".

Answer (score 43):

You can start from the scratch on **Amazon Linux ec2** instance for installing Docker by following the step:

```
sudo yum update -y 

sudo amazon-linux-extras install docker 

sudo yum install docker 

sudo service docker start 

sudo usermod -a -G docker ec2-user
```

Then logout from the instance and login again to verify the installation of Docker

```
docker info
```

To install Docker-compose follow the below steps:

```
sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/latest/download/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

docker-compose version
```

Comment: would it also work on amazon linux 2?

Comment: @PirateApp For Amazon Linux 2 you'd have to use systemctl instead of service: `sudo systemctl start docker`

Comment: You don't need this `sudo amazon-linux-extras install docker`. And update `sudo yum install docker -y`. Thanks BTW.

Answer (score 19):

Amazon Linux is "just" the OS, but compiled binaries also depend on your processor architecture. For instance, EC2 *t3a* series are based on *x86_64* architecture wheras the new *t4g* types are of *aarch64* (which is the reason I run into as similar issue as you and ended up here). `uname -m` returns that identifier, in your case apparently `aarch64`.

Since the docker-compose github repo contains no released binary for this architeture (as opposed to *x86_64*), the resolved full download URL returns a "Not found" body instead of the expected binary, thus the described error message when you try to execute it.

As you already found out, there a multiple threads which discuss this issue. The only thing that eventually worked for me was to install *docker-compose* manually via python's packaga manager *pip*. Since this approach involves a couple of compilation steps, you need to add various additional OS packages and may face other mostly dependency related errors in the process. But the following steps eventually worked for me:

```sh
uname -s -m
1> Linux aarch64
cat /etc/system-release
1> Amazon Linux release 2 (Karoo)

sudo yum install -y python37 \
    python3-devel.$(uname -m) libpython3.7-dev \
    libffi-devel openssl-devel 
# need gcc and friends
sudo yum groupinstall -y "Development Tools"
# make sure pip is up2date
sudo python3 -m pip install -U pip
python3 -m pip install docker-compose 
docker-compose --version

1> docker-compose version 1.27.4, build unknown
```

Hope it works for you as well. Good Luck!

Comment: This solution didn't help me.

Comment: you're my hero - had to drop gravitron for other incompatibilities, but this did the trick to install docker-compose

Comment: if useful, here's ready to use Ansible gist https://gist.github.com/nicolabeghin/68e4b515a8d22e36757facb5a3be58e5

Comment: Thanks. And yes, the switch was a bit painful, especially since I only picked Graviton b/c it was the cheapest recent instance type choice, without realizing first that it also involved a switch in processor architecture and Ineeded to work on my docker images. But ARM seems to get pushed more and more these days, so general support is steadily growing.

Comment: For those that missed it (like me), if you get a failure to build the wheel due to `pyconfig.h` then you forgot a yum install.

Answer (score 10):

I tried everything here mentioned, in the end, it was a problem with the symlink. The [official docker page](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/) gave me the solution.

1. `sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.1/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose`

If it doesn't work after that command, check if you can find docker in your bin folder, e.g. with: `ls /usr/local/bin/`

If you can see docker-compose there, you almost made it.

2. `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose`

An easy way to check if docker-compose is there and Linux able to find it, is to use `which docker-compose, also if it is linked correctly, you will get the path to docker-compose as a response.

This worked for me on a AWS EC2 instance with Linux2 as OS.

Answer (score 3):

## Installing Docker-Compose in EC2 instance follow below steps

**1st command**: # sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/latest/download/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

**2nd command**: # sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

**3rd command**: # ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose

**4th Command to verify docker compose**: # docker-compose version

**It will install latest version of docker-compose. 3rd command is necessary.**

Answer (score 3):

This will do everything you need.
Cut. paste. done.

`cat ec2-al2-docker-compose.sh`

```
#the following script will install docker and docker compose on amazon linux 2

# run this script then 
# sudo docker ps; docker-compose up 
# note docker-compose up doesnt use sudo

sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install docker git -y
sudo usermod -a -G docker ec2-user
id ec2-user
newgrp docker
sudo yum install python3-pip -y
sudo pip3 install docker-compose
sudo systemctl enable docker.service
sudo systemctl start docker.service
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. My configuration is **T4Large - ARM64 - Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS** and I resolved using the following command

```console
$ sudo apt install docker-compose
```

This will install the `1.25.0` version of docker compose which is a bit older. At the time of writing this answer the current version is `1.29.1`

**Another alternative** is to use `Docker Compose` as `Docker Container`.

Use the following commands to run Docker Compose Container

```console
$ sudo curl -L --fail https://raw.githubusercontent.com/linuxserver/docker-docker-compose/master/run.sh -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
$ sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

This should work on any Linux distro and on architecture like `x86_64`, `armv7l/armhf`, and `aarch64/armv8/arm64` if you already have docker installed.

The important point to note is, this runs *compose inside a container* and does not require installing python on the host system.

Docker hub reference: https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/docker-compose

Comment: thanks! this works on linux 2 arm as well